# Need help transforming a pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, tensor, semantic-segmentation

Getting this error when trying to run a version of U-net, cannot just alter the shape of the tensor, will I need to change the actual model itself?

Expected 5-dimensional input for 5-dimensional weight [16, 1, 5, 5, 5], but got 4-dimensional input of size [4, 320, 320, 24] instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model was trained on 3-D data, expecting a batch of 1-channel 3-D volume. I think your input data "squeezed" the 1-channel dimension from the 4-batch input you have of shape `4x320x320x24`. Try [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.Tensor.unsqueeze.html#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze)ing the missing dimension:

```py
x = x.unsqueeze(dim=1)  # for x of shape [4, 320, 320, 24]
```